# Objective-C: Filing an NSMutableArray with 0's and Summing Its Contents

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to create an NSMutableArray initially filled with zeroes. Over time, the array elements will change and I want to sum them. The following code illustrates two problems I'm having. First, the output from NSLog should give me a string of zeroes but it doesn't. Even though I'm doing nothing to the array, I get output like:

```
array[] = 14794004, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
array[] = 63, 30, 80828660, 80792872, 0, 80828564, 7478, 78955136, 1
```

The NSLog line is just to confirm the contents of the array. So why aren't the array elements zero and why do they spontaneously change? And once I solve the first problem how do I sum the array elements? Thanks in advance.

```
NSMutableArray *array;
int arraySum = 0;

array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,nil];

NSLog(@"array[] = %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5]), array[6], array[7], array[8];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    arraySum =  arraySum + array[i];  //Gives error: Invalid operands to binary + (have 'int' and 'struct NSMutableArry')
}                           //Isn't array[i] just one element and in this case a number?
NSLog(@"arraySum = %i", arraySum);
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray` works with Objective-C classes, not built-in C data types.

Furthermore, it does not have a subscript operator, which means you can't retrieve its contents with

```
array[n];
```

You have to use:

```
[array objectAtIndex:n];
```

**Note** that as of Xcode 4.5, the compiler does support the subscript syntax, which will be translated to the appropriate method call behind the scenes. So `array[n]` is valid in modern Objective-C.

If you want to store numeric types (`int`, `long`, `float`, `double`...) in an `NSArray`, you have to wrap them in an `NSNumber`.

```
NSArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil]
```

Then you would sum up the contents as follows:

```
for(NSNumber* num in array)
{
  arraySum += [num intValue];
}
```

Comment: Being new to both C and Objective-C, it's hard keeping the two straight. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't worry, you'll get used to it. Btw, if this answer helped you, feel free to click on the checkmark and mark it as the selected answer to your question.

Comment: This answer was correct when it was given, but support for subscripting has been added in the meantime. Since Xcode 4.5 it _is_ possible to do `array[n]`. As a bonus, `@(0)` is now available as a less verbose replacement for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]`.

Comment: @Janosch You are correct. However, you could also argue that the question itself is dated and should be revised.

Comment: @dandan78: True. Also, my comment might have been easier to see if posted below the question. But then again, as a general rule, it might be better to update old answers instead of old questions, because if you change the question, multiple answers might stop making sense. Maybe I should do a few hours of research on meta.so to decide next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

dandan78 gave a clear explanation.

Only a small note: NSArray/NSMutableArray are the DE FACTO classes to be used with cocoa.
For a "C" programmer, they are a bit strange and You cannot used pointer arithmetics, even if you see "*".

So use them, but not that for very large numeric arrays, they are very expensive and slow, compared to "C" array.